# ups 12v 9ah batteries not charging

Tags: battery-charging, ups

I have a 2000VA ups that contains 2 batteries ( 12V 9Ah ). I think that something happened to the batteries, since now they can barely handle an average laptop for about 3 minutes before shutting down the whole ups. there is any way to resurrect the batteries, or should I just buy new ones?

Comment: Wow, that's a really wimpy set of batteries for an UPS that large. Are they original? A 9-Ah battery isn't really intended to support an 80+A load!

Comment: How old are the batteries?  Was the UPS ever placed in storage for a long time?  It sounds like either the batteries are end of life or the charger in the UPS is not working properly.

Comment: The UPS was bought 3 years ago, and when it was new, it was able to sustain my 700w desktop (at least for the briefly times I needed it during outages). I went to another country for the last 2 years but the ups was being conencted to the pc all the time, and my brother was using it from time to time,  until I came back and noticed that the ups was not able to keep the computer online anymore. How can I check if the batteries could be still charged? should I unmount the batteries from the ups and charge them manually? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPS batteries usually do not last much more than 3 years, it's that easy really.

To check the battery or batteries: As your UPS is a large one I'm assuming that  it is actually has a separate battery compartment which you can access  without dissembling the whole thing.

Connect as many batteries as you need in series to get 12V and load test it which a common 12V lamp.

Charge the 12V pack with a normal automotive charger. As there most likely are several batteries in that UPS, repeat for all batteries.